# How to create a frequency distribution table on given data with Python in Jupyter notebook with as few code as possible?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, jupyter-notebook

Develop a frequency distribution summarizing this data.This data is a demand for an object over a period of 20 days.

2 1 0 2 1 3 0 2 4 0 3 2 3 4 2 2 2 4 3 0. The task is to create a table in the jupyter notebook with columns Demand and Frequency. Note: Demand has to be in ascending order. This is what I did.

```
list_of_days = [2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 2, 4, 0, 3, 2 ,3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 0] # created a list of the data
import pandas as pd
series_of_days = pd.Series(list_of_days) # converted the list to series
series_of_days.value_counts(ascending = True) # the frequency was ascending but not the demand
test = dict(series_of_days.value_counts())
freq_table =  pd.Series(test)
pd.DataFrame({"Demand":freq_table.index, "Frequency":freq_table.values})
```

The output has to be like this:

```
<table border = "1">

  <tr>
    <td>Demand</td>
    <td>Frequency</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

and so on. Is there a better way to shorten the Python code? Or make it more efficient?

Comment: A better question is **why**? If you insist though, try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: If you *really* wanted it shorter, you could just collapse some of your line-by-line statements into one line. The 7 lines you have are too many?

Comment: Why so many homework questions today?

Comment: Code review is not the optimal place to ask pandas questions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.value_counts.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and sorting by [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df1 = pd.Series(list_of_days).value_counts()
        .reset_index()
        .sort_values('index')
        .reset_index(drop=True)
df1.columns = ['Demand', 'Frequency']
print (df1)
   Demand  Frequency
0       0          4
1       1          2
2       2          7
3       3          4
4       4          3
```

Another similar solution with sorting by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_index.html):

```
df1 = pd.Series(list_of_days)
        .value_counts()
        .sort_index()
        .reset_index()
        .reset_index(drop=True)
df1.columns = ['Demand', 'Frequency']
print (df1)
   Demand  Frequency
0       0          4
1       1          2
2       2          7
3       3          4
4       4          3
```

Comment: This works efficiently, saving a lot of unnecessary conversions.

Comment: Exactly, conversions are not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

```
import collections
collections.Counter(list_of_days)
```

Should do what you're describing

Comment: Does half the job but it is efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going for the literal creation of the HTML table you posted

```
pd.value_counts([2,1,0,2,1,3,0,2,4,0,3,2,3,4,2,2,2,4,3,0]).to_frame(name='Frequency').rename_axis('Demand', 1).sort_index()
```

[image]

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>Demand</th>
      <th>Frequency</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want shortest, probably this code, Counter by default will sort the key in ascending.

```
list_of_days = [2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 2, 4, 0, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 0]  
day_counter = Counter(list_of_days).items()
data = [ [a,b] for a,b in day_counter ]
print(data)
```

> [[0, 4], [1, 2], [2, 7], [3, 4], [4, 3]]