# Frequency Distribution Table with CI, CB, F

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a Frequency Distribution Table for Statistics for school. I want to create a python script that would give me this output. I know I can just do this with excel but I want to know how to make one using python. What should I do? Thanks in advance

[image]

This is my code (I borrowed some from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41551712/14624003)):

```
import math

import pandas as pd



num = [2, 2.8, 4, 2.1, 1.8, 0.8, 1.6, 1.5, 2, 0.4, 2, 1.1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1.5, 3, 2, 1.5, 3.2, 1.2, 3, 1.2, 1.6, 2.5]
freq = ['0.4 - 1.1', 4]
# print(freq)
num.sort()  
print(f'\n{num}')


n = len(num)
R = max(num) - min(num)
k = math.floor(math.sqrt(n))
#w = math.floor(R / k) + 1
w = round(R / k + 0.1, 1)
i = min(num)
g = max(num)
R = g - i

print(f'''\nn = {n}
R = {R}
k = {k}
w = {w}\n''')


# LCI = int and float(input('LCI = '))
LCI = min(num)
# UCI = int and float(input('UCI = '))
UCI = LCI + 0.7

    
count_e = 0
print('')
for e in num:
    
    if e >= LCI and e <= UCI:
        print(e)
        count_e += 1
print('')
print(f'Frequency = {count_e}\n')
     



    


fdt = pd.Series(num).value_counts().sort_index().reset_index().reset_index(drop=True)
fdt.columns = ['Element', 'Frequency']
print (fdt)
```

Result:

```
[0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 1, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.6, 1.8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2.1, 2.5, 2.8, 3, 3, 3.2, 4]

n = 25
R = 3.6
k = 5
w = 0.8


0.4
0.5
0.8
1
1
1.1

Frequency = 6
```

Said post was mostly code but already said all i need to say...nvm this line this is just to add words

Comment: Can you explain the logic you are trying to implement?

Comment: I want to create the table that is shown in the picture. I want to make a Frequency Distribution Table for our Statistics class with python. Why python? Because I want to know how to create one using python. 

n -> number of elements in a list
R -> Range (difference of the highest and lowest values)
k -> number of classes
w -> class width
i -> lower class interval
g -> upper class interval